# Storing TrueCrypt container inside encrypted Veracrypt USB - data corruption

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

Is there any risk of data corruption if I store TrueCrypt containers inside a fully encrypted USB (USB encrypted using Veracrypt)?

Does encryption inside encryption increase chances of data corruption or other issues?

Answer (score 0):

Nested containers are supported by both TC and VC.

There should be no problem whatsoever.

There is no reason to have additional data corruption.

Sectors are encrypted individually. A bad sector of the container file data area will only affect a bad logical sector inside the container. Nothing more. The same sector would of affected the same file in the same amount for both plain writes or encrypted writes.

The only probability of corruption will be due to your storage media (the USB stick).

Comment: What if the USB device is unplugged without safely unmounting the container(s) and the filesystem(s) in the correct order?

Comment: That is not relevant. The possible data loss effects will be similar to a normal USB being unplugged incorrectly.

Comment: How is that not relevant? Data loss in a file system container == corruption

Comment: Same data loss can occur in normal circumstances. There is no difference. There will be no more or less loss compared to non-encrypted.

Comment: The same data loss in an un-encrypted file system would affect only the file(s) not flushed from write cache to device, and file descriptors... Well what if the non-flushed file is your encrypted container? It will be a lot harder to reconstruct...

Comment: No. Reconstruction will have the same difficulty.

Comment: Recreating useful info from scrambled and encrypted binary data that has been corrupted is just as easy as running fsck? Yeah! Right!

Comment: You clearly do not understood what I meant.

Comment: Clearly. Please explain.

Comment: Sectors are encrypted individually. A bad sector of the container file data area will only affect a bad logical sector inside the container. Nothing more. The same sector would of affected the same file in the same amount for both plain writes or encrypted writes. - Added to answer.